# How should I sense the presence of current in Solar-Supercapacitor circuit?

Tags: current, solar-cell, current-measurement, comparator, supercapacitor

I am trying to measure the presence of sunlight through current sensor circuit. I don't want to use LDR as it may give a false alarm if something occludes the small LDR window. Will using the board mount current sensor work given that I am trying to charge supercapacitors from solar panels? I want to use maximum solar power in my circuit.

**NOT ACTUAL SCHEMATIC**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRsIYr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 50mV current shunt and  or amplifier is my suggestion.  Cap Voltage  ought to be  80% of no load PV Voc which wont be very efficient charging up. To use maximum PV power you need a buck regulator that cuts out when PV drops below 75% on each cycle so that input voltage oscillates around the 80% with a smaller cap on input +/-5% input ripple near max power point.

Comment: how ambitious do you want to be for maximum efficiency and charge rate with voltage protection

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that one solution may be to use a high (you could also do low side) current monitor IC such as the TI [INA21x](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina210.pdf) series.

The circuit would look like this:

[image]

I'd also suggest that the diode you show (1N4148) should be replaced with a Schottky version such as a [1N5817](http://www.mccsemi.com/up_pdf/1N5817-1N5819(DO-41).pdf)

If you don't need to know the absolute current flowing, only that 'some positive' current is flowing you could even use the INA212 as a switch to measure just the Vf of the diode to infer current is indeed flowing.

The INA21x Vout = (I(load) * R(shunt)) * gain + V(ref)

Since I(load) * R(Shunt) is just a voltage, you could substitute the diode Vf.
If you don't offset by a V(ref), then the output voltage is simply Vf * gain.

The Schottky diode has a very low barrier potential, so you can actually see current flows down to around 0.1 V.
The graph below shows that at 100 mA you can expect a Vf of only 0.25 V on the 1N5817. This would work as a switch indicator down in the < 100 mA region.